# Uninstalling Windows Hotfix via C# or PowerShell

Tags: c#, windows, powershell, silent, windows-update

In our Company we need to uninstall a Windows Hotfix thats installed on the System. I've done a PowerShell Script that checks if the specified `Update` (Lookup via KBArticleID) is installed or not and then reports this via Textfile to the Server.

There is a Windows built-in Tool called *WUSA* (*Windows-Update-Standalone-Installer*) that allows to uninstall Updates with a specified `KB-Article-ID`. The Problem is that under Windows 7, 8.1 and 10 the WUSA-Tools only works in normal interactive Mode and not in the quiet Mode that we need. I'm running like this:

```
wusa.exe /uninstall /kb:3114409 /norestart /quiet
```

As described the Problem is that this command will only run in Interactive Mode and not Quiet.
Do you have any solutions or hints? I would prefer to implement this via PowerSehll or C# but other Solutions are welcome too :)

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Another approach : http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2009/03/12/how-can-i-remove-a-microsoft-update.aspx

Comment: @sodawillow That helped :) Now it works. Thanks for the Hint!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Old post, but the heck..
I tried this on a windows 2012 R2 server and it worked:
**Start-Process wusa.exe -ArgumentList '/KB:3170455 /uninstall /quiet /norestart' -Wait**